# Submit Only Selected Values in Reactive Forms Inside of FormArray

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I believe this is an easy problem but I'm confused on how should i only submit selected values on my submit button like I want that only ingredient_id and price should be appear on the console.log. I'm confused since it is inside of the formArray. Quantity should not appear on console.log?
This is my stackblitz [CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-y6gean?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
onSubmit(form: FormGroup){
    const Data = {
      values: this.addForm.get('rows').value
    }
    console.log(Data)
  }
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to remove `quantity` property? If then, why not `const values = this.addForm.get('rows').value.map(({quantity, ...obj}) => obj); const data = { values };`? See: https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automation tool you have to write your own custom output below is an example:

```
  onSubmit(form: FormGroup){
    let values_ = [];
    this.addForm.get('rows').value.forEach(item => {
      values_.push({
        ingredient_id: item['ingredient_id'],
        unit_price: item['unit_price']
      })
    })
    const Data = {
      values: values_
    }
    console.log(Data)
  }
```